# How write in files through TYPO3 Command Controller

Tags: php, linux, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I wanna create files and write in log file through a TYPO3 command controller. I have used command controller, this is registered in `ext_localconf` as `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][] = VENDOR\ExtName\Command\GeneradorArchivosEncuestasCommandController::class;`; the objetctive of this command controller is to create all templates in xlsx of a surveys of my extension domain, but in the mopment to create a file or write inside log files, I have the next error: failed to open stream: Permission denied.
[image]

Otherwise, the directories has 775 permissions and owner apache as group; and the users: `_cli_lowlevel` and `_cli_scheduler`, those user have the same file mount in BE referenced to typo3temp.

I am using TYPO3 7.6, PHP 5.6, Apache 2.2.15

Comment: You've to consider that the file-rights never work if you never use the web-server-user on cli. So either adjust the filerights to 0777 or login on cli as www-data.

Comment: Using 777 (that I think is not a good idea for possible security issues) throw me the same error `Execution of task "Extbase CommandController Task (extbase)" failed with the following message: PHP Warning: fopen(newfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /path/site/typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Classes/Command/GeneradorArchivosEncuestasCommandController.php line 32`

Comment: As in your Comment seen, I think you should add an Path to you fopen. Otherwise please show us the code where you want to open the file.